# Return the index of the last column with a specific name in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to create an excel register that counts the number of times someone has registered, and returns the date of the last time they turned up but am having trouble with this last step:

See this simplified setup:

[image]

To do this, I assume I need to find the index value of the column in which the name last appears, and the use it to return the date in the first row, the tricky part trying to get that index value.

I've tried to use lookup formulas and am pretty sure that an array formula is how this can be accomplished but am unsure how I can use them in this specific case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have Excel 2010 or later:

`=INDEX($1:$1,AGGREGATE(14,6,COLUMN(A$2:D$8)/(A$2:D$8=O2),1))`

Copy down as required.

The explanation is as follows:

The portion:

`(A$2:D$8=O2)`

simply returns an array of Boolean `TRUE`/`FALSE` values as to whether each of the cells within that range is equal to the entry in O2 or not, i.e. using your example:

`{TRUE,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE;FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE}`

The part:

`COLUMN(A$2:D$8)`

returns the column number for each column within the specified range, i.e.:

`{1,2,3,4}`

By reciprocating this array with that containing our conditional Boolean `TRUE`/`FALSE` returns, we produce an array whose only numerical entries correspond to columns in which our search string (i.e. "James") is located, since:

`COLUMN(A$2:D$8)/(A$2:D$8=O2)`

which is:

`{1,2,3,4}/{TRUE,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE;FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE}`

becomes:

`{1,#DIV/0!,3,#DIV/0!;#DIV/0!,#DIV/0!,#DIV/0!,#DIV/0!;#DIV/0!,2,#DIV/0!,#DIV/0!;#DIV/0!,#DIV/0!,#DIV/0!,4;#DIV/0!,#DIV/0!,#DIV/0!,#DIV/0!;#DIV/0!,#DIV/0!,#DIV/0!,#DIV/0!;#DIV/0!,#DIV/0!,#DIV/0!,#DIV/0!}`

by virtue of the fact that, when subjected to a suitable mathematical operation (of which division is one), Boolean `TRUE`/`FALSE` values are coerced into their numerical equivalents (`TRUE=1`, `FALSE=0`), meaning that, effectively, for any numerical value x:

`x/TRUE ⇒ x/1 = x`

and:

`x/FALSE ⇒ x/0 = #DIV/0!`

By setting `AGGREGATE`'s first parameter to 14 (equivalent to the function `LARGE`) and its second to 6 (instructing it to ignore any errors in the array passed), we can extract the largest column index which meets our criterion, such that:

`AGGREGATE(14,6,COLUMN(A$2:D$8)/(A$2:D$8=O2),1)`

which is here:

`AGGREGATE(14,6,{1,#DIV/0!,3,#DIV/0!;#DIV/0!,#DIV/0!,#DIV/0!,#DIV/0!;#DIV/0!,2,#DIV/0!,#DIV/0!;#DIV/0!,#DIV/0!,#DIV/0!,4;#DIV/0!,#DIV/0!,#DIV/0!,#DIV/0!;#DIV/0!,#DIV/0!,#DIV/0!,#DIV/0!;#DIV/0!,#DIV/0!,#DIV/0!,#DIV/0!},1)`

returns 4.

All that is left is to pass this value to `INDEX`, such that:

`INDEX($1:$1,AGGREGATE(14,6,COLUMN(A$2:D$8)/(A$2:D$8=O2),1))`

which is:

`INDEX($1:$1,4)`

returns:

`13/11/2015`

as required.

Regards

Comment: Thank you very much, it uses a lot of memory this way, but being careful about the size of the lookup helps this and it works exactly as I asked.

Comment: How does it "use a lot of memory"? What's the actual range in question? Not A2:D8? I trust you didn't use entire column references!

Comment: Every cell that you reference in that formula will be processed, whether technically beyond the last-used cell in the range or not. So you cannot reference an arbitrarily large range without detriment to performance in the belief that you are "covering your bases".

Comment: Correct, I'm using a fixed range, but with 40 days and 70 maximum names, so it's searching through a fairly large range.